# Text in Textarea changed everytime I click a different button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to make a site for documents that are stored in textareas. The layout is simple, a textarea containing the text, and a navigation bar at the top. The navigation bar has elements called Page 1 , Page 2 < page 3 and so on.

When I click page 1, the textarea must display what I wrote in page 1 in the past. When I click page 2, it should show me what I wrote in page 2 in the past. A lot like browser tabs. I don't know how I should do this.

To store the text I write in the textareas, I use a  with the hidden attribute, so I can store text there without it being seen. So when in the navigation bar I click "Page 1", it will do to the division containing the text in page 1, and paste it into the textarea.value.

The script goes like this:

```
function functionPageOne(){
   var textarea= document.getElementById('textarea');
   var btnp1 = document.getElementById('Page1Btn');
   var div1 = document.getElementById('Page1Div');
   btnp1.onclick = funnction(){
      textarea.value = div1.innerHTML; 
      alert('You are now in document 1')
   }
}
```

My real problem is how do I create new documents that work just like page 1. It should be able to create a separate DIV with a new ID accessable to the script with a add button. I hope my question makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a variable to store the content of the tabs, and create buttons to switch tabs.

When the button is clicked, store the old value of the tab to variable, and then show the value of selected tab.

If the documents need to be shared with other user or the data must persists, you will need a database. But if the documents only need to be shown to current user, you can just use localStorage API.

```js
var tabContents = {
  tab0: "",
  tab1: "content of first tab",
  tab2: "content of 2nd tab",
  tab3: "content of third tab",
}
var lastTab = 0;
// load from localstorage
// if(window.localStorage.tabContents != undefined) tabContents = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.tabContents);

function tab(idx) {
  var textarea = document.getElementById('textarea');

  // save last tab's value
  var tabnameLast = "tab"+lastTab.toString();
  tabContents[tabnameLast] = textarea.value;
  lastTab = idx;
  
  // show new tab's value
  var tabname = "tab"+idx.toString();
  textarea.value = tabContents[tabname];
  
  // save to localstorage
  // window.localStorage.tabContents = JSON.stringify(tabContents);
}

function newtab() {
  //var newtabIdx = tabContents.length;
  var newtabIdx = Object.keys(tabContents).length;
  var newtabName = "tab"+newtabIdx.toString();
  tabContents[newtabName] = "... "+newtabIdx.toString();
  var container_buttons = document.getElementById("container_buttons");
  container_buttons.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<button onclick="tab('+newtabIdx.toString()+')">tab '+newtabIdx.toString()+'</button>');
  tab(newtabIdx);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<div id="container_buttons">
  <button onclick="tab(1)">tab 1</button>
  <button onclick="tab(2)">tab 2</button>
  <button onclick="tab(3)">tab 3</button>
</div>
<button onclick="newtab()">+</button>
```

Edit: added function to add new tab

Comment: Thank you, but I have already been able to do this. I was wondering if I could make a "new tab" button and make it work like that. So that way the user can make a new tab apart from the existing tabs.

Comment: @Coolsugar answer edited to show how to add new tab button

Answer (score 2):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) API of the document's origin to store the previous page data and ready it from the storage next time. Can store data page wise like:

```
{
   page1: "<data>",
   page2: "<data>"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is a database. This is the best way to store unique data that you will reuse again.

Considering this is a JavaScript project, I would highly recommend [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/).

Comment: Thanks. This will require me to use SQL yes? I haven't really gotten into SQL just yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: if you need to store persisting data then you need database, but if it's just to be shown to user then database is overkill

Comment: You’re welcome. MongoDB is actually NoSQL. Easy to scale and very easy to learn.